# Use htaccess to validate with php before granting access to a directory

Tags: php, validation, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm working on an app where users can create an account and upload images, which get stored in a directory and can then be displayed within the application itself or in a publicly visible part of the app. Now I'd really like to protect the images to ONLY allow access to these images in the event that certain conditions are met, i.e, a session is set or the permissions in the db for the image are set to public, to name a few.

So, what I'd need is that whenever an image from that directory is loaded, the htaccess file passes the image name onto a php file in that directory, which runs whatever checks it has to, and if it returns true, htaccess can proceed with spitting out the image (whether it's in an  tag or just entered in the address bar of the browser).

I've trolled through many posts but haven't found anything. I can't imagine it's not possible, so anyone who can offer guidance will be prayed for - and if you're local, well, other benefits may be in store!

Comment: This is possible & quiet easy but what have you tried so far? You seem to know what you want, start coding and you might surprise yourself

Comment: See [`http://www.jasny.net/articles/how-i-php-x-sendfile/`](http://www.jasny.net/articles/how-i-php-x-sendfile/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Store the uploaded images in a non web-accessible folder, then
Use a rewrite rule to forward requests to php; Something like: `RewriteRule ^images/([^/]+) /image.php?img=$1 [NC]`

Do your validations in the php and if ok forward the image from the non-readable folder via php; something like

```
header('Content-type: '.$mime);
header('Content-length: '.filesize($filename));
$file = @ fopen($filename, 'rb');
if ($file) {
  fpassthru($file);
  exit;
}
```

Comment: Think readfile will suffice for what I was after. However, I would need to store the files in a web accessible folder because we're running on multiple servers and have dedicated storage boxes.

Answer (score 3):

If I were you I would move all of your images to a certain folder and then build a php script like this called image.php:

```
<?php

// You may want to use image name depending on 
// if you can fetch the name from the db from an id
// You need the filename to open the image later

$iid = 0;
if(isset($_GET['iid']))
    $iid = (int)$_GET['iid'];

// Check session
// Check database permissions ect.

// If you don't want this image to be output call die();

// If it's a go, output the image.

// Change this to the type of the image you're about to output
header('Content-Type: image/png');

readfile('images/'.$image_filename);

?>
```

You can set up your .htaccess like:

```
RewriteRule ^images/(.*)$ image.php?iid=$1 [L]
```

So that when a request is made for `images/10.jpg` it instead calls your script with `iid=10.jpg`

You can change your .htaccess a bit, depending on whether you want to use ids or filenames and such, you might not want the .jpg passed along. Same with the script. Let me know if you have any questions :)

Comment: as far as I see, it will ruin animated gifs if there's any

Comment: @Greenisha True, but that's a minor thing and an easy fix. You just call `imagegif($image);` instead if it's a gif

Comment: Using the image library like this is very inefficient and impractical -- you've already got images, you don't need to spend cycles to convert them into the format that they're already in. Just call readfile() on the filename.

Comment: Thanks guys I will try this out. Think this will work. Presumably this php file that validates can't be in the same folder as the images themselves, but that's OK. Will readfile() also work for audio and video files?

Comment: Worked like a charm. I'd initially tried something but was putting the php file in the folder as the images. DOH!

Comment: Another question here: When I'm writing my Rewrite Rule in the htaccess file, can I somehow also pass the URL that is calling it, i.e., the referring URL along with the iid as another variable to my php file? Thanks a million!

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand your case, you need to close direct access to files by .htaccess

deny from all

and make an PHP front-end in another directory, that will take path or just picture filename from $_GET and check if conditions are met and return image, for example

```
header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
readfile("/path/to/my/images/$image");
```