# How to validate a User IP before opening a file in browser in PHP?

Tags: php, validation, ip-address

My website hosts a PDF file www.abc.com/abc/xyz.pdf - where if some one opens this link in browser they get the PDF.

I need to write/implement a PHP script before opening the PDF, which checks the IP address of the user who is requesting the PDF file against IP addresses that are available in an array.

The PHP script should run in background or something. As my users will click directly on the pdf link and that PHP validation script needs to be executed and redirect accordingly.

Any help in validating these users is appreciated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6817918/use-htaccess-to-validate-with-php-before-granting-access-to-a-directory?rq=1 and a gazillion similar questions.

Comment: Because your visitors might use a dynamic IP, it might be a better user experience if you choose a different authentication method.

Answer (score 2):

```
$ips = array('127.0.0.1', '34.43.43.12');

if(!in_array($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], $ips))
{
 echo 'no access';
}
else
{
  //access
  header('Content-type: application/pdf');
  readfile('file.pdf'); //change location to your file
}
```

You could find this code. Try do some research before posting a question next time.

Comment: I was thinking if it is possible to run this script in background on clicking the pdf link. Once validated it will open the pdf or it will give 403 error.

Comment: You can do whatever you want to get 403 error use instead of `echo 'no access';` this one `header('HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden');` you can use .htaccess and `deny from all` and later `allow from IP`

Comment: is it possible to use this format (43.43.43.0/50) on the array list?

Comment: @MarkGerrylMirandilla it is but $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] will give you IP and you want to ask for Network Address so if you want to do it then you'll need to get IP with  $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] convert it to binary and apply binary mask equal to 50. I did it on my github repository you can check https://github.com/rpodwika/network-calculator

Answer (score 1):

Use this to get IP of client system : `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']`